# Reading table from geodatabase via ArcPy and doing what each row in field says after geopandas conversion?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

Here is the table:

#### Reproducible example

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'id': [1, 2, 3], 'table_na': ['ER_ASTEN_ASTOT', 'INT_ASTEN_ASTOT','ER_ASTEN_ASTTOM']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

which gives:

```
   id   table_na
0   1   ER_ASTENOT_ASTOTA
1   2   INT_ASTENOT_ASTOTA
2   3   ER_ASTENOT_ASTTOM
```

I would like to read a table that looks like the above that I have in a `gdb` using Arcpy.

For every row in the `table_na` field, when it sees the `ER` or `INT` it should get the [`Erase`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/erase.htm) or [`Intersection`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) function in Arcpy respectively and use the relevant shapefiles (`ASTENOT`,`ASTOTA`,etc) for the calculation in a loop sequence.

---

I have already done this using `geopandas` but the process was very slow. In similar situations using ArcPy was very efficient. I do not have much experience in ArcPy which is why I am asking this question.

Here is the code in Geopandas I used to do the process and to help you help me:

```
#this reads the guide ex.ER_ASTENOT_ASTOTA from a txt.

import os
import fiona
import geopandas as gpd
rootdir = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\a' # path to root directory you walk
sfiles = {} # a dictionary with all the .shp files
for entry in os.listdir(rootdir):
    dirpath = os.path.join(rootdir, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(dirpath): 
        for file in os.listdir(dirpath): # Get all files in the subdirectories
            if file.endswith('.shp'): # If it's an .shp.
                filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
                sfiles[filepath[:-4]] = gpd.read_file(filepath)


action_dict = {'INT': 'intersection', 'ER': 'difference'}
directory=input('Insert dir of the main folder')
with open(input()) as txtfile: #insert directory of txt
    x = txtfile.readlines()
for line in x:
    action, shape1, shape2 = line.split('_')
    print( action, shape1, shape2) # here line is ER_ASTOM_ASTIK or whatever line in your txt file
    if shape1 in sfiles and shape2 in sfiles:
        a=gpd.overlay(sfiles[shape1], sfiles[shape2], how=action_dict[action])
```

Comment: Portion of answer (how to read from GDB) already provided in separate question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299386/how-to-read-line-by-line-a-column-from-a-table-in-a-gdb-using-arcpy. OP still needs assistance with performing specific arcpy functions based on the table.

Comment: What kind of naming convention are you using for your outputs?

Comment: the same with the rows. Example: The output of ER_ASTENOT_ASTOTA is called ER_ASTENOT_ASTOTA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below assumes you're at the stage of `for row in cursor: action, shape1, shape2 = row[0].split('_')` from your other question [How to read line by line a column from a table in a gdb using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299386) -- see there for code snippet to read from the GDB table.

```
outname = row[0] # update naming convention / path here (default is saved in workspace, e.g. gdb). 
if shape1 in sfiles and shape2 in sfiles and action == "ER":
    # Code sample and documentation for arcpy Erase: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/erase.htm
    in_features = shape1
    erase_features = shape2
    arcpy.Erase_analysis(in_features, erase_features, outname)
elif shape1 in sfiles and shape2 in sfiles and action == "INT":
    # Code sample and documentation for for arcpy intersect: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm
    infeatures = [sfiles[shape1], sfiles[shape2]]
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis(inFeatures, outname)
else: # different action code or one of the files doesn't exist?
    print("Error processing {}".format(outname))
```

Comment: Looks promising, how the shape1 was created?Like in the question?Does it need it anything differently since it is in Arcpy? I am upvoting and will check it out extensively after i finish with another part I am working on.

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote yet. Low on points. I am accepting and will read it later.Thanks for the help.

Comment: `shape1` etc. are coming from the row[0].split('_'). I assumed that your `sfiles` dictionary is working fine from the geopandas version of your code.  Make sure you set your environment workspace (`arcpy.env.workspace = pathtogdbfd`).

Comment: Can you tell me how to convert this line: ` sfiles[filepath[:-4]] = gpd.read_file(filepath)` ? It's in the middle of the code?

Comment: Please add as a new question.I'm not familiar with geopandas. It looks like that's trying to open the shapefile as a geopandas data frame. http://geopandas.org/io.html.  You don't need to explicitly open the file for most of the arcgis tasks. But what needs to be stored in the dictionary is likely the filename or path in the workspace.

Comment: I actually solved it with `sfiles[filepath[:-4]] = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()`

Comment: Excellent. Keep in mind that ListFeatureClasses depends on the current workspace. Another tool to explore is arcpa.da.walk, or for shapefiles one of my favorites is glob.

Comment: Yes, I am working da.walk right now! glob is great but I don't think it works with arc.py.

Comment: glob works fine with shapefiles, but cannot access geodatabase layers (da.walk can).