# Reading column line by line from table in geodatabase using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, cursor

I have a table in a geodatabase.

It looks like this:

```
   id   table_na
0   1   ER_ASTENOT_ASTOTA
1   2   INT_ASTENOT_ASTOTA
2   3   ER_ASTENOT_ASTTOM
```

It has more columns though.

Can you tell me how to read the column table_na line by line?

Example, reading by a txt:

```
with open(input()) as txtfile: #insert directory of txt
    x = txtfile.readlines()
```

But I have to read from this specific column only.

Also tried this (with cursor):

```
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\05052\MyProj.gdb"

datasetList = arcpy.ListTables("*")

for dataset in datasetList:
     with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dataset, "*") as cur:
          for row in cur:
              print row
```

But gives all that is in that table in one line.

Comment: The SearchCursor documentation covers this. You already have everything you need *except* an explicit list of field names and the iteration of the row array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close. If you want to access just a single column, you can pass in the column name and then access in the cursor using the position within the row. (You can also request multiple fields in this manner; just add the field name into the list within da.SearchCursor.) Your code, modified, below:

```
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\05052\MyProj.gdb"

datasetList = arcpy.ListTables("*")

for dataset in datasetList:
     with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dataset, ["table_na"]) as cur:
          for row in cur:
              print row[0]
```

Another example with more than one field:

```
for dataset in datasetList:
     with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dataset, ["mytestfield1", "mytestfield2", "table_na"]) as cur:
          for row in cur:
              print row[2] #retrieve table_na
```